# Same code for 4 boxes, different output

Tags: css, position

I'm struggling to understand the positioning concept, so I created a simple code which includes 4 boxes with identical width and height settings. when positioning it as fixed or absolute it looks fine and identical, but when positioning it with static or relative the boxes change proportions.can someone please explain? I change the boxes border color so it will be easy to differentiate between them

```css
.box {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 25px solid;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  fond-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="border-color:green;">Box1
  <div>
    <div class="box" style="border-color:yellow;">Box2
      <div>
        <div class="box" style="border-color:blue;">Box3
          <div>
            <div class="box" style="border-color:pink;">Box4
              <div>
```

You can also view the code on next link [1](http://codepen.io/Yonatanos/pen/VPyqMo)

Code's output [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spp8M.jpg)

Comment: You're not closing your divs tags properly. Should be `</div>`

Comment: Thank you for your support and patience!

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't properly close your div elements, the browser attempts to correct the mistake by doing it for you, however in the process this creates a different hierarchy. Something like this:

```
<div class="box" style="border-color:green;">Box1
  <div>
    <div class="box" style="border-color:yellow;">Box2
      <div>
        <div class="box" style="border-color:blue;">Box3
          <div>
            <div class="box" style="border-color:pink;">Box4
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is causing your situation. Just change your closing div tags to `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct. By using div instead of /div after each box, you are essentially nesting these boxes.

Here is corrected HTML:

```
<div class="box" style="border-color:green;">Box1
</div>
<div class="box" style="border-color:yellow;">Box2
</div>
<div class="box" style="border-color:blue;">Box3
</div>
<div class="box" style="border-color:pink;">Box4
</div>
```

And the CSS you had stays the same:

```
.box {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  border: 25px solid;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  fond-weight: bolder;
}
```